# Possible to run scripts on sleep and wake?

Tags: macos, automator, sleep-wake, script

MacBook Pro 2010 running OS X Lion.

Is it possible to run scripts on sleep and wake events?

My specific application is that I've got Dropbox-synced Truecrypt volumes that  I regularly use on both my MacBook and iMac. I rarely shut down my MBP since closing the lid is much faster and easier, but this means that I have to remember to dismount my Truecrypt volumes and let them sync back up before closing my MBP. It's trivial enough to script mounting/dismounting of them, but I'd like to go a step further and have these scripts run automatically.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It appears that as the OS ships, [sleep/wake cannot trigger scripts](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=36967), but third party solutions have been developed.

- [Scenario](http://www.lagentesoft.com/scenario/index.html) appears to be one such solution.
- [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/) also seems to add some script triggering abilities. I can see it can trigger scripts on [wake from sleep](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2014-10-09-run-script-on-mac-power-on-or-wake/index.html) and it can [trigger scripts on sleep](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2015-10-27-fleeting-sleep/).
  [image: Power Manager - trigger on power on screen shot]

I have no personal experience with these programs or their vendors.

Comment: Scenario seems to do what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I had Scenario fire the applescript which fires off a bash script and voilá.

Comment: To end an application just type this in a new AppleScrip window and save it in the SleepScripts folder: tell application "CodeBox"
 quit
end tell

Answer (score 26):

[SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/) may be of use.

From the description: *It can be used to execute a Unix command when the Mac or the display of the Mac goes to sleep mode or wakes up, after a given time without user interaction or when the user resumes activity after a break or when the power supply of a Mac notebook is attached or detached. It also can send the Mac to sleep mode or retrieve the time since last user activity.*

It's working fine for me on 10.6.8. Various versions are available to support 10.1(!) thru 10.7

Comment: Here are a bunch of [Mac OSX Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/search.php?query=sleepwatcher&keyType=all&datestart=&dateend=&topic=0&type=stories&author=&mode=search) that use SleepWatcher.

Comment: You can install SleepWatcher by [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), e.g. `brew install sleepwatcher`. And see [this post](https://www.kodiakskorner.com/log/258), it's very helpful. The SleepWatcher utility also supports OS X El Capitan (10.11).

Answer (score 11):

This is my own app, so consider that, but ControlPlane has the ability to do actions based on Sleep/Wake. You'll find it at http://www.controlplaneapp.com/.

ControlPlane is a fork of MarcoPolo and has been updated to run on Snow Leopard and Lion.

Comment: Very cool sounding utility, its overkill for just this but if you have a need to trigger on more than wake/sleep then it sounds pretty cool. I like the Growl support also so you know what it is doing. And its free :).

Comment: Should be the accepted answer because its free

Comment: can this used for mounting and unmounting drives with sleep and wake ? do we need  to write automator scripts ?

Comment: years later, controlplane is now unmaintained due to buildup of incompatibilities that Dustin posted on his blog that he didn't have time to fix. Too bad, makes sense though.

Answer (score 8):

I developed the following simple Launch Daemon to provide a 'wake' trigger for scripts on Leopard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>wake-alert</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>z=/tmp/wake; test -s $z || { date > $z; say w; }; 
tail -1 /Library/Logs/DirectoryService/DirectoryService.server.log | grep -v Sleep || > $z
        </string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/Logs/DirectoryService/DirectoryService.server.log</string>
    </array>
    <key>ExitTimeOut</key>
    <integer>2</integer>
    <key>ThrottleInterval</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You can replace 'say w' with your code. I write a date to z but you could change this to write anything. You may need to increase 'ExitTimeOut' for some scripts. My Launch Daemon resides at /Library/LaunchDaemons/wake-alert.plist

The Launch Daemon watches DirectoryService.server.log and writes to a temporary file provided the file is empty. The file is cleared by a log 'Sleep' entry and by Shut Down.

If you use 'fast user switching' to sleep you will find that scripts which require a logged in user will attempt to run too early and fail unless you modify the Launch Daemon - perhaps grep 'Succeeded' in 'secure.log'.

Comment: `/Library/Logs/DirectoryService/DirectoryService.server.log` doesn't exist in High Sierra (10.13).

Comment: There are probably other logs which can be used.

Answer (score 6):

Was interested in that question previously but didn't find any step by step guide on how to achieve it. 
Solution is based on open-source tool called [sleepwatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/) and apple [launchd](https://www.launchd.info/)
Was inspired by [this](https://www.kodiakskorner.com/log/258) article

So enjoy! :

1. Install sleepwatcher => `brew install sleepwatcher`
2. At first create => `~/.wakeup` and `~/.sleep` scripts and put some shell logic into it
3. Add necessary permissions => `chmod 700 ~/.sleep && chmod 700 ~/.wakeup`
4. Test it locally => `/usr/local/sbin/sleepwatcher --verbose --sleep ~/.sleep` - go to sleep with running terminal
5. If it works then load process as launchd agent for all users => `/Library/LaunchAgents`
6. Add symlink for sleepwatcher launchd task => `sudo ln -sfv /usr/local/Cellar/sleepwatcher/2.2/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher-20compatibility.plist /Library/LaunchAgents/`
7. Load launchd task => `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher-20compatibility.plist`

Hope it will help anybody :)

Comment: sleepwatcher does not work for me on calalina wih an internal SSD disk. I guess the SSD is so fast that the computer sleeps before the script can run.

Comment: Does not seem to work on me. I'm on Catalina and simply running `/usr/local/sbin/sleepwatcher --verbose --sleep ~/.sleep` hangs up.

Comment: @user3056783 I think it actually works as it should hang if u are running it in terminal. That's why it should be run as a daemon process via LaunchAgents as I mentioned in further steps.

Comment: this DOES work for me in Catalina! You can just do `brew install sleepwatcher` to get it. Thanks!

Comment: for me this worked: `brew services start sleepwatcher; sudo cp /usr/local/Cellar/sleepwatcher/2.2.1/etc/sleepwatcher/rc.* /etc` and then adding the `~/.sleep` file.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) (https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/), no affiliation.
It can trigger an action when system goes to sleep or wakes up among tons of other features to ease working with Mac.

[image]

I used the sleep/wake events to trigger a url that connects to an IOT device that I designed to control an external fan that I put on top of the Mac Mini (Mac is upside down).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another program which you might discover and be tempted to try is [EventScripts](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/eventscripts/id525319418?mt=12).  Although it is a very impressive program which I would recommend in general, after testing it for this purpose it does ***NOT*** actually appear to be able to trigger scripts quickly enough for them to run before your Mac goes to sleep, and instead the sleep script will not run until after the Mac has woken up, which (obviously) defeats the purpose.

I hope to save you and anyone else reading this the hours of testing it took me to come to this conclusion.  I'm sorry to have to say that it failed, however, because in so many respects it is a really nicely designed and quite powerful and flexible program.  It's also quite inexpensive ($3).  The low-level performance just doesn't seem to be there, however, for running a script ***before*** sleeping.

On the other hand, in my tests (so far) [sleepwatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/) has appeared to be quite reliable and fast.  It's also free, which is awesome.  I'll keep testing and if I find it to not work sometimes I'll update my answer, and keep testing other options.

***UPDATE*** I have *not* found sleepwatcher to be consistently reliable since originally writing this answer, although it initially appeared to be working.  In my case I don't need to run arbitrary scripts, but instead just eject external drives.  I've found a small and inexpensive app that does this very well so far: [Jettison](http://stclairsoft.com/Jettison/index.html).  This has very quickly become one of a small handful of utilities I can't live without.  If your needs are the same as mine, I think you'll find it well worth the few bucks they charge.

Answer (score 2):

[WakeWatcher](https://github.com/erluko/WakeWatcher/) is a simple OS X faceless background application I created to address this issue. It runs `~/.onwake` whenever wake is detected. You can then put the commands to mount/remount your drives in that script.

WakeWatcher is suitable for use as a login item. It is not very sophisticated, but it is free and simple.

To execute scripts on sleep would be a simple addition, but I'm concerned about the time available for the scripts to complete before the system actually does sleep. If you really need it, open an issue against the github project and I'll add it.