# Automatically launch Safari with a certain URL the first time the Mac wakes/boots up in a day?

Tags: startup, automator, script, automation

Is it possible to make my Mac automatically open a website on Safari the very first time it is woken up just once in a day?

So for example, I come to work at 8:30 and wake up / boot up my Mac and Safari automatically opens up on a certain URL.

But then I go for lunch and turn it off / make it sleep and come back an hour later and this time nothing happens. And maybe i have a meeting and come back later and still nothing happens.

Until the next day this process repeats (only opening Safari the very first time)

Sorry, i'm not sure how to even google for this.

I thought maybe "Automator" could do something like this but i think it requires me to manually click on it.

**Edit**: I've opened a bounty on this same question at SuperUser: [Automatically Launch safari with a certain url the first time the mac wakes/boots up in a day?](https://superuser.com/questions/1151650/automatically-launch-safari-with-a-certain-url-the-first-time-the-mac-wakes-boot/1152701#1152701) if anyone is interested.

I'm running macOS Sierra (Version 10.12.1) and Safari (Version 10.0.1).

Comment: It would be helpful if we knew what versions of both macOS and Safari you're running.

Comment: I'm running macOs Sierra (Version 10.12.1) and Safari (Version 10.0.1).

Comment: Why the double-post?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is duplicating and promoting a question on another site (SuperUser)

Comment: Crossposting is [not good etiquette on StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), please choose one question and close the other.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Automator for this.

1. Open Automator
2. Choose type: Calendar Alarm
3. Drop action 'Get Specified URLs' in
4. Drop action 'New Safari Documents' in
5. Save Automator action
6. Give the Calendar alarm a name
7. The Calendar app will open now
8. Edit the Calendar event - repeat every day at 08:30

[image: Automator action]

Comment: Do I need to keep the calendar app open for this to be triggered?

Answer (score 0):

OS X has no built-in triggers for running actions on sleep or wake, but there are several third-party solutions—see the answers to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27036/possible-to-run-scripts-on-sleep-and-wake) for several options (the question is a few years old, but some of the apps mentioned certainly still exist).

Once you have the ability to run a script on wake, one approach would be to  check the timestamp of a hidden file that you create in the user's home directory. If the timestamp is today, do nothing. Otherwise, run your 'open url' action, then [touch](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/touch.1.html) the hidden file to update its timestamp.