# Big Sur, sleep and networking

Tags: network, sleep-wake

M1 MacBook Air, Big Sur 11.6 ...

Back on Sierra I could stop network connections from being torn down when I closed the lid; is there a way to achieve this for the current iteration of hardware and OS?

I couldn't find anything in the system settings to that effect.

Comment: There seems to be no official way to disable what used to be called "Power Nap" on Intel machines. Apple advertises m1 Macs as "always on" and the preferences for Power Nap have vanished on Apple Silicon machines. Perhaps as a workaround you could run some automation to close undesired apps or turn off the network interface when your Mac goes to sleep (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316686/automator-workflow-to-close-programme-when-laptop-is-closed-goes-to-sleep)

Comment: Tanks @KevinGrabher Well, yeah ... that's a possibility.  My beef w/ that solution is that it's not a solution. I'm a sysadmin, often run terminal tasks on other machines but occasionally have to attend meetings (to which I need to take the laptop). I guess I'll have to force myself to run everything in `screen/tmux` sessions remotely and bite the bullet and re-authenticate against the VPN after every meeting =/