# Run cron script at wakeup

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, script, cron

I would like to run a script at wakeup. So my laptop is sleeping, I open the lid, and the script should run immediately or within the minute after wakeup. This script should run at startup as well, as that is essentially the same situation.

**How can I run a cronscript at either wakeup and startup?**

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27036/possible-to-run-scripts-on-sleep-and-wake

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run a cron task at wakeup. It is possible to run a script at wake with some third party utilities. This thread is old, but probably still relevant.

[Possible to run scripts on sleep and wake?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27036/possible-to-run-scripts-on-sleep-and-wake)